# Saving related entities in EF with transient dbContext fails

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a asp net core 3.1 web application. We use repository pattern with entity framework.

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnString")), ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
```

Made up scenario, just bec everybody knows the "Customer-orders"-scenario:

When I create a new Order and want to connect it to an existing Customer I write something like this. Works ok.

```
var order = new Order(){...}
order.Customer = _dbContext.Customers.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.CustomerId = 42);
_dbContext.Orders.Add(order);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

However. For other reasons we need to have dbContext transient, initiated like below:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnString")), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

This makes the code above fail. Error message is the Customer is already attached to dbContext *("The instance of entity type 'Customer' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'CustomerId'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, , ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached")*

or, if I test setting order.Customer = null:

The error message says "cant insert Id on identity column" (which it shouldnt, the customer already exists). (*"Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Users' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."*)

Comment: `EFCore` behavior varies across different versions. You should state clearly what version of EFCore you are using? In this case u've 3 options: (1) Use `AsNoTracking`, `order.Customer = _dbContext.Customers.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(c=>c.CustomerId = 42)` (2) Create a customer instance and attach to dbContext `order.Customer = new Customer { CustomerId = 42 }; _dbContext.Attach(order.Customer);` (3) add the Order first before setting its Customer `_dbContext.Orders.Add(order); order.Customer = _dbContext.Customers.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.CustomerId = 42);`. I'm not sure if any working however.

Comment: The suggestions above may work or not depending on the behavior of the specific EFCore you're using. I saw it too complicated and not tried to remember the behaviors of each specific version. Trust try it out to see if it works. `EFCore` is still developing so we usually just need to care about the latest behaviors, which should be the most natural and desired behaviors (from the developers' standpoint).

Comment: Do you now have CustomerId on the Order? that way you won't need to do the fetch of customer. `Order.CustomerId = 42`

Comment: Agree with KingKing, try to set your dbContext to Notracking Behaviour, like this: `services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer( Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")).UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking), ServiceLifetime.Transient);` Reference: [The instance of entity type cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/12459)

Comment: Ok, I got away with setting   _dbContext.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;...but then I had to save each order one by one, Ill defenately test the NoTracking for the entire dbcontext later today. I guess this is what I wanted all the way-